# JavaScript - Duplicate Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions for two different events using a selector.

```
$("#textArea").keyup(function(){
    if ($("#textArea").val != "") {
        document.getElementById("btnPost").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("btnPost").disabled = true;
    }
});

$("#textArea").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

The problem is that, only one of the functions is being run. Is having two events for the same selector acceptable in JQuery ? Is it possible to make these two events be detected using the same selector ? In this two functions, only the first one is being run, the one for disabling a button. How can I make the other one work ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having two events target the same selector is perfectly fine. If only one of the two events is triggering, the problem will be with your `if` condition **logic**. Your first condition isn't triggering because you're looking for the method **[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** rather than `.val`.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
$("#textArea").keyup(function() {
  if ($("#textArea").val() != "") {
    console.log('Up: Filled');
  } else {
    console.log('Up: Empty');
  }
});

$("#textArea").keypress(function(event) {
  console.log('Press');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="textArea">
```